# Checkmarx - Reflected XSS in a AWS lambda function

Tags: javascript, typescript, checkmarx

```js
export const handler = (
  handleGetRequest: Function,
  handlePostRequest: Function,
  handlePutRequest: Function,
  handleDeleteRequest: Function
) => async (
  request: i.LambdaEvent,
  context: i.LambdaContext,
  done: i.LambdaCallback
) => {
    handleGetRequest = JSON.parse(sanitizeHtml(JSON.stringify(handleGetRequest)));
    // handle requests
};
```

In the above file I receive a Reflected XSS error when running checkmarx on line 2 and 3 respectively that handleGetRequest and handlePostRequest are not sanitized.

I tried to sanitize it as an object with this code :

```
handleGetRequest = JSON.parse(sanitizeHtml(JSON.stringify(handleGetRequest)));
```

but I still have same error.

The question is how can I sanitize these 2 Function objects to pass checkmarx check?